# kendo UI Treeview throws an exception - r.Dragging is not a function

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

I am using kendo ui with requirejs. I am using multiple widgets just fine, but when I try to initialize a treeview I get an exception - r.Dragging is not a function'

```
var inlineDefault = new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({
          data: [
            { text: "Furniture", items: [
              { text: "Tables & Chairs" },
              { text: "Sofas" },
              { text: "Occasional Furniture" }
            ] },
            { text: "Decor", items: [
              { text: "Bed Linen" },
              { text: "Curtains & Blinds" },
              { text: "Carpets" }
            ] }
          ],
          dragAndDrop: false
        });

       $("#treeview").kendoTreeView({
          dataSource: inlineDefault
        });
```

the exception is:

Uncaught TypeError: r.Dragging is not a function
f.ui.DataBoundWidget.extend.init @ kendo.all.min.js:formatted:18252(anonymous function) @ kendo.all.min.js:formatted:732

couldn't debug the issue, am I missing a dependency (i have jquery) or something? that code is taken from their examples...

Answer (score 0):

try this fix

```
var inlineDefault = new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({
          data: [
            { text: "Furniture", items: [
              { text: "Tables & Chairs" },
              { text: "Sofas" },
              { text: "Occasional Furniture" }
            ] },
            { text: "Decor", items: [
              { text: BED LINEN" },
              { text: "Curtains & Blinds" },
              { text: "Carpets" }
            ] }
          ]
        });

   $("#treeview").kendoTreeView({
      dataSource: inlineDefault,
      dragAndDrop: false
    });
```

Comment: the dragAndDrop property was indeed in the wrong place but it wasn't the problem. I got a new version from Telerik that fixed the problem